# Simple Prolog Program - Is a value inside or outside of a range?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program that takes 3 integers I, J, and K and returns true if K is in the range of I and J and false if it falls outside the range.

The logic is super easy of course, but I am not understanding the syntax of Prolog enough to implement it.

How would I go about solving this task. This is the code I've currently got:

```
i(10).
j(20).
k(21).

inRange(i, j, k):-
   (k > i, k < j).
```

Comment: Do you know in advance that X < Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule of Prolog's syntax one needs to remember is that the case of the first letter in things that start in a letter matters: what looks like a variable in many other languages may actually be an *atom* in Prolog.

If an identifier starts in a lower case letter, it's not a variable, it's a so-called *atom*. Unlike variables, atoms are constant. They cannot be bound to other values by means of *unification*, so `inRange(i, j, k)` cannot possibly work. You need

```
inRange(I, J, K) :- K > I, K < J.
```

Now your logic works as expected:

```
:- inRange(0, 10, 5), write(yes).
```

writes `yes`, while goals

```
:- inRange(0, 10, -1), write(yes).
:- inRange(0, 10, 11), write(yes).
```

both fail. Here is a [quick demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/4zrnBy).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use variables (which must begin with a capital letter):

```
in_range(X,Y,Z) :- X < Y, X < Z, Y > Z.
```

Now depending how you define something to be in the range, you maybe would prefer:

```
in_range(X,Y,Z) :- X =< Y, X =< Z, Z =< Y.
```

These two versions require that all three numbers are instantiated, which means, you can only ask a question like:

```
?- in_range(1,10,4).
true.
```

but not:

```
?- in_range(1,10,X).
X=1;
X=2;
...
X=10.
```

How about the built-in predicate `between/3`? Try it out with:

```
?- between(1,5,3).
```

or

```
?- between(1,5,10).
```

or even:

```
?- between(1,5,X).
```